# are continuous functions that map measure zero sets to measure zero sets absolutely continuous?

Tags: real-analysis, examples-counterexamples

Let $I$ be a closed interval and $f:I\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function which maps measure zero sets to measure zero sets.

If $f$ is monotonically increasing, $f$ must be absolutely continuous.

However, is the monotone assumption necessary?

Is there a continuous function mapping measure zero sets to measure zero sets but not absolutely continuous?

Comment: I think you need to have bounded variation in there in some fashion. Monotonicity is one way to get it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a theorem that if a function is continuous, bounded variation, and has the "Luzin N property" (i.e. maps measure zero sets to measure zero sets) then it is absolutely continuous. One way to get bounded variation is to assume monotonicity but this is not the only way. However, if you don't have bounded variation then you will not have absolute continuity. In particular:

$$f : [0,1] \to \mathbb{R},f(x)=\begin{cases} x \sin(1/x) & x \neq 0 \\ 0 & x=0 \end{cases}$$

is a continuous function with the Luzin N property which is not absolutely continuous. To see that you can simply bound its variation below by $\sum_{k=0}^\infty |f(x_k)-f(x_{k-1})|$ where $x_{-1}=1,x_k=\frac{1}{\frac{\pi}{2}+k \pi}$.

Comment: and I guess that bounded variation and Luzin N $\implies$ absolutely continuous is done by showing [the singular part](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lebesgue%27s_decomposition_theorem) of the signed measure $\mu([a,b]) = f(b)-f(a)$ is zero ?

Comment: @user1952009 Actually you need continuity in there too. The sign function is not absolutely continuous but it is BV and has the Luzin N property. At the end of the day the proof boils down to what you said, because a simple characterization of an AC function $f$ on a bounded interval is that it is differentiable a.e. and $f'$ integrates to give $f$. Differentiable a.e. follows from bounded variation so all that is left is to show the singular part vanishes.